# Deeplab v2 error: undefined layer "IMAGE_SEG_DATA"

Tags: deep-learning, caffe, image-segmentation

As I tried to run "run_pascal.sh" in deeplapv2, I got the following error:

Unknown enumeration value of "IMAGE_SEG_DATA" for field "type".

I found a [solution](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/caffe-users/O8lSpI-DOQY) stating that I should change the type of the layer from "IMAGE_SEG_DATA" to "ImageSegData", but the solution didn't work.

Finally, I found the definition of this layer in "image_seg_data_layer.cpp". However, this layer isn't defined in the "caffe.proto".

I traced back to the "caffe.proto" of deeplab v1 and there is actually an enumeration value named IMAGE_SEG_DATA.

Please show me how to fix this problem!

Comment: Do you solve the issue? I have same issue

Comment: Uhm, I forgot to change "layers" to "layer", which help me go a bit further. However, this framework is driving me crazy.  I think the authors built this framework on top of old caffe version using old style params which are no longer exist on the new caffe.

Comment: Thanks. Do you means change layers to layer in test_val and train? I tried to replated it in test_val.prototxt and it got new error `[libprotobuf ERROR google/protobuf/text_format.cc:245] Error parsing text-format caffe.NetParameter: 13:9: Expected string.`

Comment: Yea, Deeplab and anything that builds on it are very hacked together networks for semantic segmentation. I have heard people having more success with things like [FCN](https://github.com/shelhamer/fcn.berkeleyvision.org) and DilatedNets, but not much success on my own. Have you moved to a different network? if so, what?